# Using 'conditional' transitions with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a sort of simple question.  Im building a carousel which rotates vertically using vue.  When the user clicks the forward button, I want vue to transition the elements in/out using my 'forward' transition (moving them down).  When the user clicks the backward button, I want vue to transition the elements in/out using my 'backward' transition (moving them up).

Right now, I just have one transition that performs my forward transition, whether the user is navigating forward or backward.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Heres my component:

```
<template>
<div class="carousel__container">
    <div class="carousel__visible">
        <div class="carousel__slides">

            <transition-group name="carouselNext">
                <div v-for="(quote, index) in quotes" class="carousel__slide" key="index" v-show="index === currentSlide">
                    <blockquote>{{ quote.quote }}</blockquote>
                    <cite>{{ quote.cite }}</cite>                   
                </div>
            </transition-group>

        </div>


    </div>

    <button class="btn btn--alt" @click="prev">Back</button>

    <button class="btn btn--primary" @click="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easiest way is to change the transition name based on direction 
`<transition-group name="carouselNext">` can become `<transition-group :name="direction">`

add new `direction` data var and include toggling based on methods

```js
    prev(){
      this.direction = "carouselPrev"
      this.currentSlide = (this.currentSlide + this.quotes.length - 1)%this.quotes.length
    },
    next(){
      this.direction = "carouselNext"
      this.currentSlide = (this.currentSlide + 1)%this.quotes.length
    }
```

and finally add the alternate `carouselPrev` css transition classes

here's a working example https://codepen.io/scorch/pen/NwwpxM